# Flavor vs efficiency

Tags: regex

Speaking in terms of efficiency between using the `OR`, `AND` operators or back to back character classes.

In the below string data.

```
1A
A1
$1
$$
```

The following expressions:

```
^[\w\W][\w\W]$

^(?:\w|\W)(?:\w|\W)$

^[\w&&\W](?:[\w&&\W])$
```

How will consistency take affect here and what is really the difference here, besides an individual's desired flavor of using an expression?

Comment: IMHO, the only significant difference here is that the first one is really quicker to read and to write... `;)`

Comment: @sp00m Wouldn't `^..$` be even quicker? =P

Comment: The first is shorter but In my opinion the 3 are crazy. You will better write something like : `^(?s)..$` or `^[\s\S]{2}$` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the http://regex101.com/ regex debugger you can see the differences of how the pattern is matched. The main difference is speed:

- `^[\w\W][\w\W]$` needs 6 steps to match one of your strings
- `^(?:\w|\W)(?:\w|\W)$` needs 10 steps to match one of your strings
- `^[\w&&\W](?:[\w&&\W])$` needs 8 steps to match one of your strings

Of course this highly depends on the regex flavour, the implementation of the engine and possible optimizations.

**edit**:

- `^..$` needs 6 steps as well

The number of steps doesn't necessarily directly correlate to speed, however in most cases (if the regex is trivial enough), a readable and better maintainable regex provides more benefit then the speed savings of xy microseconds (again depends on the use case and input data).